# 4G Modem Huawei HiLink - can't connect

Tags: drivers, internet, modem

***Modem Huawei E3372H***

Changed firmware from windows with special program, it should be now (I don't know how to check if it is really so):

```
WEBUI_17.100.06.00.03_Hilink_v7r2_9x25
```

When I connect it in my ***Linux Mint XFCE***:

- nothing visually happens on the screen
- no device seen in Modem Connection
- GUI modem indicator ***blinks green (frequently)***
- I don't see any new device beside my normal ethernet port available in add
  connection settings, trying to add ethernet connection
- I tried to add ethernet connection, but I don't see any new device beside my normal ethernet port available in add connection settings
- ***http://192.168.1.1 - doesn't connect***
- I see device in lsusb:

  > **lsusb**
  >   Bus 001 Device 010: ID 12d1:1c05 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband stick (modem on)

**How can I setup internet throw modem?
What are my next steps?**